# How to save wav file in static files?

Tags: c#, api, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I'm developing a simple API to a school project and I'm using text-to-speech cognitive services from azure and i write a text and transform to wav file, but if i want to do deploy, how can i save the wav file and acess the file after?

here is my code:

```
public void TexttoSpeech(string text)
    {
        string audiofile = "Audio.wav";
        var folder = Path.Combine("StaticFiles", "audios");
        var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), folder, audiofile);

        var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("subscription-key", "brazilsouth");
        var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromWavFileOutput(path);

        speechConfig.SpeechSynthesisLanguage = "pt-BR";
        speechConfig.SpeechSynthesisVoiceName = "pt-BR-AntonioNeural";


        var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

        synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(text);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ConversaoTextoPFala(string text)
    {
        try
        {
            _speechRepository.TexttoSpeech(text);
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            return BadRequest(erro);
        }
        return StatusCode(201);
    }
```

Comment: checkout the SetOutputToWaveFile Method.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.setoutputtowavefile?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: You **must** `await` the `SpeakTextAsync` method.

Comment: Use the method `SetOutputToWaveFile()`.

The following code block will help to give the folder path to store the audio after successful TTS.
`synth.SetOutputToWaveFile(@"localpath\sample.wav",new SpeechAudioFormatInfo(bitrate(12000), AudioBitsPerSample.Sixteen, AudioChannel.Mono));`

For the reference Checkout the document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.setoutputtowavefile?view=netframework-4.8#system-speech-synthesis-speechsynthesizer-setoutputtowavefile(system-string-system-speech-audioformat-speechaudioformatinfo)